# iOS Swift - Firebase custom event logging not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have set my app to log analytic events to Firebase

I have carefully followed the [official Firebase tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/start)

I have also watched the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=5&v=5pYdTgSkW5E)

I have added the FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled to my scheme as you can see in the image

[image]

I have ensured that events have no white spaces (underscores instead)
and that they meet the character limit

My Firebase core and Analytics are set correctly because I can see the standard set of Firebase events that are automatically logged and general statistics etc but **NONE OF MY CUSTOM EVENTS ARE LOGGED**

here is an example line of code I use to log a simple event (string):

```
    Analytics.logEvent(eventName, nil) //eventName is a string
```

This is what I see in the xcode debug console upon custom event logging:

```
    myapp[2977:1016413] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS000000] Logging event: origin, name, params: auto, error (_err), {
```

This debug information tells me nothing and i'm not sure FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled is even working correctly

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong ?

Comment: Where are you looking for the logged events? In DebugView in the console?

Comment: In Firebase console > Analytics > events

Comment: Events can take several hours to appear in the console. I'd check out [DebugView](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#reporting) first to see events in real-time.

Comment: Thanks will check it out. It's been days but I'm sure there's something I'm overlooking. Just wish the debug logging actually helped me understand what

Comment: Also remove this if its in your ENV VARs ... OS_ACTIVITY_MODE

Answer (score 7):

I also ran into same issue and I tried adding `-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled` and `-FIRDebugEnabled` in scheme, also tried setting `IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED` to true in `GoogleService-Info.plist` but no trace of firebase event logs in XCode console. What worked for me was unchecking `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` in edit scheme and my console was flooded with log events of firebase. Hope this helps someone.  [image: Scheme Edit Snap]

Comment: Today I`ve encountered this issue, good catch.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with your event parameters.

Please change your code to this:

```
Analytics.logEvent(eventName, parameters: nil)
```

If that doesn't work then send an empty array:

```
Analytics.logEvent(eventName, parameters: [])
```

or for Swift 4.2:

```
Analytics.logEvent(eventName, parameters: [:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's to late, but if your events does't works also you doesn't get messages in debug screen:

There are in GoogleService-Info.plist, try to change value of IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED to YES

Answer (score 0):

Just download the file `GoogleService-Info.plist` from Firebase again, and make sure `do not` change anything then replace that file in you XCode then everything should be okay.